# c++: Making a vector of linked lists

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm forming a very primitive hash table. How do I create a vector where each individual index can lengthen into its own list? Is it as simple as, for example, `vector<list<int>>` ?

Also, if I want each node of the linked list to hold two datatypes (i.e. a string word and the integer line numbers of the file it can be found in), is it possible? I imagine not.

Comment: what do you want exactly? hash table? or vector of lists?

Comment: It is possible, you can encrypt the string and then do something like `hash = encrypted_string * 1000000000 + integer_value`.

Comment: I'm looking for a vector of lists. It's not a true hashtable, I know. It's kind of a lead into them, though.

Answer (score 2):

`vecotr<list<int> >` seems fine to me.

For you second question, you can use

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> Item;
std::vector<std::list<Item> >
```